# Safety of subclass data when returned as superclass

Tags: java, polymorphism, return-type

I'm having some trouble finding the specifics on what happens when you return a subclass in a method of superclass type in Java. For example:

```
    public class SuperClass
    {
        int a;
    }
    public class SubClass extends SuperClass
    {
        int b;
    }


    SuperClass superObj;
    SubClass subObj;

    private SuperClass getObject ()
    {
        return subObj;
    }


    public static void main (...)
    {
        superObj = getObject();
    }
```

What exactly happens to subObj when it's returned as its superclass? I realise while typing this example that I could probably just as easily test it myself, but i'm still curious as to what the process is exactly when this happens, and whether it's considered good (if it works, that is) or bad practice.

I'm asking because I'm currently working on a project in which I have two abstract base classes, and several subclasses for each of them. I'm trying to find out good/bad ways to handle having to change from one subclass to another while still using the convenience polymorphism adds when using abstract base classes.

EDIT: I fixed main and the class declarations, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some oddities in your code (defining a method inside main?), but that not withstanding... The method getObject will not change your subObj, it will simply return a reference to it that looks like type SuperClass. By "looks like" I mean that it will only expose any methods or members from SuperClass. However, if you take that returned value and attempt to downcast it to SubClass, the cast will succeed and you will find the field/methods from SubClass will work as you expect without any loss of information from having been returned as SuperClass.

Answer (score 1):

Casting does not fundamentally change an object to a different type, it simply tells the compiler to view the object as its superclass (or subclass, when downcasting).  In your example, superObj is still an instance of the SubClass type, but it now *appears* to be a SuperClass.  What this means is that if you try to reference `superObj.b`, you will get a compilation error (since b does not exist in SuperClass).  However you could reference `(SubClass)superObj.b`.  In this case you are telling the compiler to consider subClass as an instance of SubClass (which it really is).

Let's take this a step further and add another class to your code:

```
public class SisterClass extends SuperClass
{
    int c;
}
```

Without changing anything else in your code (other than the syntax problems), you try to reference `((SisterClass)superObj)`.  This will compile but fail with a ClassCastRuntime runtime error.  Although SisterClass is a subclass of SuperClass, superObj is *not* an *instance* of SisterClass.  So, you can only cast to what the object actually *is*.

Answer (score 0):

SubClass is extension of SuperClass

you are just casting it down to its base class, all extensions are not available, you should not be looking to try and get them back to Implementations as you would be guessing what that are, as you could extend it numerous times in various ways,

The returned class would have **a** but not **b**

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that if you have a reference to an object of type SuperClass then Java will allow you to interrogate it to determine if it is a more specific type (in this case SubClass) and will let you downcast where appropriate.

Comment: @tuckermi it would indicate poor design if you returned the Basetype in the first place.

Comment: While that is often true, there are certainly cases where down casting is acceptable. And, more to the point, I think it's worth mentioning because it highlights what the JVM is doing as compared to how up casting may be handled in other languages/runtimes.